# Getting an error when attempting to call a function

Tags: python, function

I am a beginner in Python and I am trying to write a program that is essentially a "fortune teller" using functions. I seem to be having an issue when calling a function get_today() which is written to take an input form the user for the day of the month, and return it as an integer.

However when I call on the function I am prompted with an error that goes:

```
TypeError: get_today() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'
```

I've tried playing around a bit and cannot figure out what this means. Here is the main function:

```
def main():

    print("Welcome​ ​to​ ​Madame​ ​Maxine's​ ​Fortune​ ​Palace. Here,​ ​we​ ​gaze​ ​deeply into​ ​your​ ​soul​ ​and​ ​find​ ​the secrets​ ​that​ ​only​ ​destiny​ ​has​ ​heretofore​ ​known!")
    print("")
    print("The​ ​power​ ​of​ ​my​ ​inner​ ​eye​ ​clouds​ ​my​ ​ability​ ​to​ ​keep track​ ​of mundane​ ​things​ ​like​ ​the​ ​date.")
    d = get_today()
    print("Numerology​ ​is​ ​vitally​ ​important​ ​to​ ​fortune​ ​telling.")
    b = get_birthday()

    if(d >=1 and d <= 9):
        print("One more question before we begin.")
        a = likes_spicy_food()
        print("I will now read your lifeline")
        read_lifeline(d,b,a)
    if(d >= 10 and d <= 19):
        print("I will now read your heartline.")
        read_heartline(d,b)
    if(d >= 20 and d <= 29):
        print("I need one last piece of information.")
        m = get_birthmonth()
        read_headline(b,m)

    if(d == 30 or d == 31):
        print("Today is a bad day for fortune telling.")

        print("These insights into your future are not to be enjoyed or dreaded, they simply come to pass.")
        print("Good day.")

main()
```

This issue will likely repeat when the second function get_birthday() is called, which asks the user for the day of the month they were born.

Here is the code snippet for get_today():

```
def get_today():

        x = int(input("Tell​ ​me,​ ​what​ ​day​ ​of​ ​the​ ​month​ ​is​ ​it​ ​today:​"))

        return x
```

Help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: For one thing, the function `get_today` takes an argument but when you all it in `main`, you don't give it any arguments. It looks like you don't actually need the argument for `get_today`, so remove the `d` in `def get_today(d):`

Comment: Well when you're calling `get_today` you're not passing an argument to it for a start...

Comment: removing the d prompted me with a new error `TypeError: get_today() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run this code as is, it doesn't give me your error. However, when I run this code with `d = get_today()` as `d = get_today(d)` under `main`, I get the error you're getting.

When you call a function, what goes between the parentheses is what gets passed into the function. Since you don't have `d` assigned yet, you can't pass it in. In addition, your function doesn't need variables to be passed in since all it is is the user input.

Try this:

```
def main():
    #code
    d = get_today()
    #more code

def get_today()
    #the function with return statement

main()
```

Comment: removing the d prompted me with a new error `TypeError: get_today() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'`

Comment: Did you remove `d` from `def get_today()`?

Comment: Yes, I will post what the edit looks like in the original question. @Brandon Molyneaux

Comment: And I'm presuming you removed it from `main` as well?

Comment: Yes, I did indeed.

Comment: It shouldn't toss you an error if there's nothing in the parenthesis in both the call and the function. Try restarting your kernel and opening a new document and typing in the bare minimum (like I have above) and running it. Then copy and paste it as necessary in the script and see if that works.

Comment: After moving it into another document I just received the error message: `NameError: name 'get_today' is not defined`